# How to use cameraX with SurfaceView/TextureView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-jetpack, android-camerax, android-textureview

I am planning to migrate camera api to camerax. Currently I am using SurfaceView to show the camera preview. I noticed that camerax is using PreviewView to show the camera preview. As this library is still in alpha stage, so what is the alternate for that?

I know that previewView internally using SurfaceView/TextureView.

How can I explicitly configure and use SurfaceView/TextureView?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using PreviewView. Managing the Surface correctly requires working around many corner cases. If you insist of writing your own code, please take a look at PreviewView's implementation and start from there.

See: [SurfaceView implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f2e05c341382db64d127118a13451dcaa554b702/camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/SurfaceViewImplementation.java) and [TextureView implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f2e05c341382db64d127118a13451dcaa554b702/camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/TextureViewImplementation.java)

Comment: Yes. It is better to use PreviewView.